# MySQL Advanced ORDER BY Clause for message reply system

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a page where users can post message. For each message posted someone can make a reply that will be shown right after the original message.

See my MySQL Table :

```
id | user_id  | message                    | date                | second_reply_id
1    48         Hi i post a message          2013-08-08 13:00:00   0
2    20         Hi i also post a message     2013-08-08 14:00:00   0
3    17         And i reply to message 1     2013-08-08 15:00:00   1
4    8          And i reply to message 2     2013-08-08 16:00:00   2
5    10         Hi i post a new message      2013-08-08 17:00:00   0
6    7          i reply to reply id 3        2013-08-08 18:00:00   1
```

Is there a way to order the result of the select query like this :

```
id | user_id  | message                    | date                | second_reply_id 
5    10         Hi i post a new message      2013-08-08 17:00:00   0
2    20         Hi i also post a message     2013-08-08 14:00:00   0
4    8          And i reply to message 2     2013-08-08 16:00:00   2
1    48         Hi i post a message          2013-08-08 13:00:00   0
3    17         And i reply to message 1     2013-08-08 15:00:00   1  
6    7          i reply to reply id 3        2013-08-08 18:00:00   1
```

Thank you

Comment: can you have a reply to a reply?

Comment: How do you distinguish between replies to the two top-level posts?

Comment: @JeremySmyth i assume by date...

Comment: Hi, yes someone could reply to a reply but it will be shown at the same level at the first reply. (it's just a @stephan i reply to your reply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (unfortunately this will not work if you can reply to a reply):

```
SELECT
    id ,
    user_id,
    message,
    date,
    second_reply_id
FROM 
    my_table 
ORDER BY
    second_reply_id,
    IF(
        second_reply_id = 0,
        id,
        second_reply_id
    )
```

**UPDATE:** to order also the replies from oldest to newest just use :

`ORDER BY IF(second_offer_id =0, id, second_offer_id ) ASC , IF(second_offer_id =0, 'xxxx', date ) DESC`

Comment: This would be my choice, although I think you need to add second_reply_id to the end of the order by clause (to force the original message to come before replies to that message).

Comment: @Stephan. I removed ORDER BY second_reply_id (used only IF) and it works (even with reply from reply). Now i don't know if it's possible but i would like to order the main message so it shows the most recent message first.

Comment: @yves strange that its working with reply to reply... it can be a coincidence due to the ids used ... can you show me the sample data ? also yes you can just add in `ORDER BY` the `date` column

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35072/discussion-between-stephan-and-yves)

Answer (score 1):

JOIN the table to itself ad order by reply_to_id and date